# Rest API in Jenkins to get the Pipeline (stages) information

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm exploring the options to get the pipeline (stages) information in Jenkins through Rest API. We had a pipeline plug-in installed on Jenkins.

Any help on same is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can see some documentation on some endpoints in the [*Pipeline: REST API* plugin README][1], but otherwise this question is lacking details and is more of a "where is this documented" type question, so I am voting to close.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use this endpoint to get the pipeline runs:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-stage-view-plugin/tree/master/rest-api#get-jobjob-namewfapiruns

Each run blob should contain the corresponding stages, so you can extract the stages of the latest run.

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for now for several hours. Thank you.